# Validate IP addresses in user input with batch script

Tags: windows-xp, batch, ip, regex

> **Related:**
>   [Script to assign and remove arbitrary secondary IPs to an interface](https://superuser.com/questions/363932/script-to-assign-and-remove-arbitrary-secondary-ips-to-an-interface)

I'm trying to augment the script in the above question, by validating the user input so that the script will only work with valid IP addresses and subnet-masks. I'm aware there are a number of different regular expressions available that will check IPs, but I don't know how (or even if there is a way) to use this against the variables in my batch script with native Windows XP commands.

Can someone point me in the right direction, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been tinkering.  Don't ask me why... but here is quite an extensive check for your ipaddress/gateway/subnet-mask:

```
@Echo Off

set NEW-IPADDR=192.168.1.2
set NEW-MASK=255.255.255.240
set NEW-GW=192.168.1.1

set RETURN=isValidIP
goto checkIP

:isValidIP
echo.We are good to go.

REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Do whatever with the IP/mask/GW here.  The values appear to be valid.
REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------
goto :End

:checkIP
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%a in ("%NEW-IPADDR%") do set ip1=%%a&set ip2=%%b&set ip3=%%c&set ip4=%%d
set /a decIP=(16777216*%ip1%)+(65536*%ip2%)+(256*%ip3%)+%ip4% 2> nil
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%a in ("%NEW-MASK%") do set mask1=%%a&set mask2=%%b&set mask3=%%c&set mask4=%%d
set /a decMask=(16777216*%mask1%)+(65536*%mask2%)+(256*%mask3%)+%mask4% 2> nil
set /a netAddr="%decIP%&%decMask%" 2> nil
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%a in ("%NEW-GW%") do set gw1=%%a&set gw2=%%b&set gw3=%%c&set gw4=%%d
set /a decGW=(16777216*%gw1%)+(65536*%gw2%)+(256*%gw3%)+%gw4% 2> nil
set /a gwNetAddr="%decGW%&%decMask%" 2> nil


set isBadLabel=badIP
if %ip1% EQU 127 (goto :badIP)
if %ip1% EQU 0 (goto :badIP)
set num=%ip1%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%ip2%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%ip3%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%ip4%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)

set isBadLabel=badMask
set num=%mask1%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%mask2%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%mask3%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%mask4%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)

set isBadLabel=badGW
set num=%gw1%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%gw2%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%gw3%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)
set num=%gw4%
call :checkNum
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto :End)

set testmask=-2
set bcast=0

:loopmask
  set /a testmask=%testmask%+%testmask%
  if %decmask% EQU %testmask% (set bcast=%testmask%)
if %bcast% neq 0 (goto :goodMask)
if %testmask% geq -16777216 (goto :loopmask)

:badMask
echo.Bad subnet mask. (%NEW-MASK%)  Check and try again.
echo.
goto :End

:badIP
echo.Bad IP Address. (%NEW-IPADDR%)  Check and try again.
echo.
goto :End

:goodMask
set /a bcast="%bcast%^-1"
set /a bcast=%netAddr%+%bcast%
if %decIP% equ %bcast% (goto :badIP)

if %decIP% equ %decGW% (goto :badGW)
if %gwNetAddr% neq %netAddr% (goto :badGW)

if %decGW% equ %bcast% (goto :badGW)
if %decGW% equ %netAddr% (goto :badGW)

goto :goodGW
:badGW
echo.Bad Gateway Address. (%NEW-GW%)  Check and try again.
echo.
goto :End

:goodGW
goto %RETURN%

goto :End

:checkNum
set badNum=0
set /a numval=%num% 2> nil
if "z%num%" neq "z%numval%" (set badNum=1) else (
  if %num% GTR 255 (set badNum=1) else (
    if %num% LSS 0 (set badNum=1)
  )
)
if %badNum% equ 1 (goto %isBadLabel%)
goto :EOF

:End
```

It even works in vista, and 7.

*---- whops forgot to check if the gateway is the net address/broadcast address. ----*

Comment: Wow.  I'm going to have to sit down with this and pick it apart sometime.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why I did all of this.  imho... The only confusing bit is when I did the subnet mask checking, I started with -2 and doubled it repeatedly.   why a negative number? well batch files are processed in a 32-bit environment (even in 64-bit windows) with a signed integer.  -2 = 0xFFFFFFFE = 11111111111111111111111111111110.  I initially double it before I bother using that as a mask... so we start with 11111111111111111111111111111100 which translates as 255.255.255.252 which is the first usable subnet-mask.

Comment: It should check the following: are the values in each octet between 0 & 255.  does the IP start with 127... is the subnet mask actually valid... is the IP the network-address or broadcast address... is the gateway inside the same subnet as the IP... etc...

Comment: Wow.  That's a lot more than I'd have bothered to have it check.  I would have been fine with each octet being <=255, really.  If you could add more comments to the code, to help explain the usage and functions of some of the commands, it would be great.  If not, I'll edit it in when I have time to pick it apart myself later.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, the initial three `SET` lines should be `SET /P` since the intent here is to validate IPs input by the user - not included in the script.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant that I plan on using this for a script that will configure IP, Subnet, Gateway, DNS, and WINS - with some additional error checking to skip the latter three if those values are left empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FindStr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) with RegEx's:

> **/r** : Uses search strings as regular expressions. Findstr interprets all metacharacters as regular expressions unless you use /l.
>
> Using regular expressions with findstr
>
> Findstr is capable of finding the exact text you are looking for in
>   any ASCII file or files. However, sometimes you have only part of the
>   information that you want to match, or you want to find a wider range
>   of information. In such cases, findstr has the powerful capability to
>   search for patterns of text using regular expressions.
>
> Regular expressions are a notation for specifying patterns of text, as
>   opposed to exact strings of characters. The notation uses literal
>   characters and metacharacters. Every character that does not have
>   special meaning in the regular expression syntax is a literal
>   character and matches an occurrence of that character. For example,
>   letters and numbers are literal characters. A metacharacter is a
>   symbol with special meaning (an operator or delimiter) in the
>   regular-expression syntax.
>
> The following table lists the metacharacters that findstr accepts. 
>   [image]

Keep in mind that FindStr's RegEx system is not as robust as many others, so not all Regular Expressions will work without a little modification.

Comment: `Findstr` *finds* text, but can it return input to the batch script as to whether or not the text was found in a way that I can use for an `IF` statement?